# Started explorer.exe as different user, can't switch back

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, runas

I have two domain accounts (user and admuser) which I'm working with on my Windows 10 Pro machine. Yesterday, as 'user' I Shift+RightClick on C:\windows\explorer.exe and choosed Run as Different User and entered the credentials of the 'admuser' because I wanted to directly use the network drives mapped to the admuser without log off/on. 
It worked but now I can't switch back to an explorer running as 'user' even after logging in and out as 'user' again. Whenever I login as 'user' my explorer.exe gets started as 'admuser'? what am I missing? How can I switch back?

Comment: Have you tried killing all Explorer instances in Task Manager?

Comment: Yes. Tried that several times. I even tried a runas command from the task manager "start new task" menu point

Comment: Are the credentials available in the credential manager?

Comment: Have you tried to repeat the run-as of explorer.exe with your own credentials?

Comment: How have you determined that explorer is running as your admin user? Try running [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and double-click the process entry for explorer.exe. What user does it say it's running as?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Twisty Impersonator comment pointed me in the right direction. explorer.exe gets executed as 'user' as it is supposed to be but some logon scripts messed up my mapped network paths. after net use * /delete and a reboot everything is fine now.